# A word for "in terms of time"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What is the word that describes the context of time to replace e.g. "in terms of time, ..."

Like I can say,

- It is more tiring mentally than physically;
- <strike>It is longer physically than "in terms of time"</strike> *(perhaps modelled on [**"it" = "an eclair"**](http://www.crossword.org.uk/chambers.htm))*
- It is very costly both financially and "in terms of time"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second one seems very odd. What does "longer physically" mean? Taller? How do you compare this with time "length"? And what could it mean if you did?

Comment: it is just an arbitrary example, but makes a good riddle I guess?

Comment: A good riddle hasta have an answer. Why **is** a raven like a writing-desk?

Comment: I'm glad I Googled that first. :) or I can't sleep tonight.

Comment: BTW, if you're gonna talk about grammar etc, it's vitally important to pick good examples, because otherwise nobody can understand what you're talking about. Grammar is very finicky stuff and everybody seems to use their own terminology, so examples are the only way to go. And random examples -- not such a good idea; make every word count, and no distractions.

Comment: @JohnLawler just for fun, can I suggest the answer to be a "light-year"

Comment: @JohnLawler: The canonical answer to "Why is a raven like a writing desk?" is "I haven't the slightest idea." ^_^

Comment: I think [the apparent absence of a single word for "time-consuming"](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081010094648AAhOMnF) (requiring much time) along the lines of *tiring* (requiring much effort) and *costly* (requiring much money or figurative substitute) is probably relevant to OP's concerns.

Comment: @John, Robusto: I'm guessing what OP has in mind is that long-deleted whimsical Chambers Dictionary "famous definition" for **eclair** [*'a cake long in shape but short in duration'*](http://www.crossword.org.uk/chambers.htm).

Comment: @JohnLawler Reminds me of the music-hall joke. 'Porter, I've just missed the train to London. How long will the next one be?' 'About the same length as the one you missed, mate!'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Timewise*** is used in the sense you are seeking.

timewise (not comparable)

With respect to time.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/timewise

Answer (score 3):

*Chronologically* is perhaps a slight stretch (OED “In a chronological manner or order; in or according to order of time”), but probably less likely to be misunderstood than *temporally.* Or perhaps *chronometrically,* “[in a manner] relating to the measurement of time.”

Answer (score 1):

The sentence could be rephrased to read something like: '*It is very costly **and time-consuming***.'

Sometimes there just isn't a word to fit a certain syntax, without resorting to esoteric terms which may intonate a sentence or phrase in an unusual or garish manner.  Gallicisms and borrowed German *portmanteau* words can often be employed in such instances where one feels semantically *zugzwanged*... **if** one is *accoutred* with the verbal wherewithal to do so, that is!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the word ***temporally*** (adverb) is what you could be looking for? E.g., the adjective "spatiotemporal" describes something in terms of space ("spatio-") *and time ("temporal")*.

See [here](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/temporal) for some definitions of the word ***temporal*** (adjective), in which the second definition can be located and identified apparently with what you're looking for:

> (*formal*) connected with or limited by time 
>   <sub>- *a universe which has temporal dimensions*</sub>

Out of the word "temporal", the word "temporally" may be constructed. "Temporally" may modify "temporal" in a manner which could translate the concept of something being described "in terms of time" as you are looking for. This idea I infer from [here](https://www.lexico.com/definition/temporally). (The latter link exposes a definition of "temporally" with respect to UK-English usage, whereas the former link exposes the above-said definition of "temporal" with respect to American-English usage; however, I think the difference between the English usages is so subtle that, in this case, it remains negligible.)

Comment: No; in this sense, 'timewise' is the correct choice. There are a few hundred results in a Google search for "is costly timewise" but zero for "is costly temporally". The wrong register.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ok. Thanks for the clarifier.